# Adding a indicator / panel in unity panel

Tags: unity, indicator, panel, unity-2d

In GNOME panel we could add a notification indicator by doing "Add to Panel".
How to do the same in Unity 2D?

Well what I mean is how to add additional indicators like Weather, RSS... that seems to be missing as I cannot right click on the panl and add one.

Comment: Well what I mean is how to add additional indicators like Weather, RSS... that seems to be missing as I cannot right click on the panl and add one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither Unity or Unity 2D will support applets, see here for more information:

- [Can I use GNOME applets in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10597/can-i-use-gnome-applets-in-unity)
- [What Application Indicators are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/list-of-application-indicators) has alternatives

[Unity Lenses](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/Places/) might be an option if you'd like to extend Unity.

Comment: Thanks Jorge, I read thru that and seems like Places is the best option.

Answer (score 7):

A possible alternative I found is to add a gnome panel to unity.
You can experiment the solution by open a terminal and type

gnome-panel

I placed one single gnome panel at the bottom of the screen. In that panel you can place whatever you want as usual. It's also good for find resources, open windows and administrative tools (not immediate to find with unity interface).

If you like the solution you can autostart your new panel everytime you log in by adding an entry in: administration->session (or something similar, I haven't English locale set).

I hope this help

Comment: thx! I would like to link it to this [question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/39069/how-do-i-use-the-gnome-panel-in-unity) too