# How to add another panel?

Tags: unity, panel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding a indicator / panel in unity panel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25979/adding-a-indicator-panel-in-unity-panel)

I want to add a new panel other than the Top one.

Is that possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2):

Unity gives you only the top panel. But you can install an additional panel, like tint2 or gnome-panel and add it to your autostart programs.

Comment: Florian, I've noticed you don't include much detail in many of your answers (they just say "you can't do xyz". Please tell the user HOW to do this.