# How can I  import my Gnome Sticky Note Applet notes into Tomboy?

Tags: unity, tomboy

After moving to Unity, I found that I lacked access to my sticky notes I had created in Gnome using the Sticky Notes Applet.

Tomboy is the default option for sticky notes in Unity, and so moving the content into Tomboy was required. The best way I found to do this is to:

```
cat ~/.gnome2/stickynotes_applet
```

and manually port the content of the notes into new Tomboy notes.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]This should be done automatically. If you take a look at Preferences->Add-Ins there is the Sticky Notes Importer under Tools. This should be active.

Comment: You beat me to it. my rambling had me end up with Sticky Notes Importer aswell. I deleted my post since I am ashamed of it :+)

Comment: FYI there is a bit related [question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/35713/simple-gnome-applets-in-unity-stickynotes)