# How can I bring gnome sticky note back in unity?

Tags: 11.04, unity, applet

If I'm right, panel applet is no longer supported in Unity.
How can I bring sticky notes back?
Is there any application or AppIndicator that has the same functionality (like show all notes when logged in)?

Not tomboy please :), I don't like its interface.

Comment: added [bug](http://pad.lv/778750)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Indicator-stickynotes](https://launchpad.net/indicator-stickynotes) is maybe the applet your looking for !

Written in Python, and using GTK 3 library. Current version is 0.3, but works well. You'll have to add this ppa to enjoy this application :

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:umang/indicator-stickynotes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-stickynotes
```

[image]

- You can lock/unlock, hide/unhide your notes from the panel.
- Change notes color
- Create as many post-it as you want

[See here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-to-start-applications-at-startup-automatically-in-unity) to run indicator-stickynotes on startup.

Comment: There are 2 big disadvantages in Indicator Stickynotes.

1) You can't have notes of different colors

2) There is no keyboard shortcut to hide / unhide.

Old Sticky Notes was much simpler and better, in my opinion. I'm also looking for a way to have it on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Thank you very much. This works perfectly in my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: not working well on ubuntu 14.04 , after minimizing , completely crashes

Answer (score 3):

See [“Simple” gnome applets in Unity - stickynotes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35713/simple-gnome-applets-in-unity-stickynotes)

And here [How do I use the GNOME Panel in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39069/how-do-i-use-the-gnome-panel-in-unity)
 Until someone makes an indicator for it those look like your work arounds.

Answer (score 1):

Try Xpad : http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/08/xpad-simple-sticky-notes-for-your-desktop/

You can click on this link to install : [Xpad](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xpad)

Comment: Xpad has the same problem. Big buttons and feels a bit to clumpy...

Comment: Doesn't seem to stay visible on 13.04 .

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it personally but [**this**](http://www.iloveubuntu.net/indicator-stickynotes-03-released-settings-dialog-and-keyboard-shortcuts) indicator applet tries to copy the functionality of the old notes applet.