# Will I be able to load my sticky notes or I will have to type them again?

Tags: 12.04, notes

I have many notes in my system. But I see that sticky-notes has disappeared in ubuntu12.04. So what should be done?

Answer (score 2):

Your notes should not have been deleted, but Ubuntu 12.04 does not comes with XPad pre-installed. So you should [install](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xpad) it.

Comment: I mean the notes from the sticky notes program. It seems that th program doesn't exist anymore. It was opened and closed from an applet in the gnome-panel

Comment: Do you mean this: http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xpad ? As referred here: http://www.tejasbarot.com/2012/02/25/howto-installing-sticky-notes-on-linux-fedora-ubuntu/

Comment: No. I don't like xpad. At least it is ot good with this "stone in the shoe" called Unity. It is this: http://library.gnome.org/users/stickynotes_applet/stable/stickynotes-introduction.html.en   |It is mentioned here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/35713/simple-gnome-applets-in-unity-stickynotes , but I never finish reading threads and links and links inside the links.... I get nowhere.

Comment: Have you tried this: http://askubuntu.com/a/40027/12943 ?