# Gbirthday - Is there a way to let it work with Unity

Tags: unity, evolution, panel, compatibility

As a follow-up to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72145/do-you-know-any-birthday-reminder-alternative-to-gbirthday), the very useful and small birthday (and more) reminder tool [Gbirthday](http://gbirthday.sourceforge.net) does not seem not work with Unity. Is there a way to tweak this, so Gbirthday works in Ubuntu with Unity?

Normally there would be a small icon in the panel, but I guess Unity does not like "foreign" items in the panel.

Comment: @Bruno Pereira Thanks for the attention, but this is not a duplicate. I intentionally posted two different questions, to get different answers: First how to make gbirthday work with Unity, secondly are there any alternatives to gbirthday. Aren't these two different questions? Please open this question again, thanks in advance.

Comment: **VTR:** 2 separate questions by same user referencing the other now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make any program that used to use the old notification system in Gnome 2.0 (the panel before Unity) show up in the new panel in 11.04 and 11.10 by whitelisting it.  There are directions in this blog post:

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/how-to-re-enable-notification-area.html

If you don't like the command line, skip down to section B in the instructions (B. Using a GUI).

Comment: @Omegamomegil Now it works on my computer as well, although only partially. The list of birthdays is not complete in the pop-up window. It only shows one entry per day, even if there are several, but this a gbirthday problem. And better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I found another solution, not as elegant as the above:

If there is a Gnome Panel applet that you absolutely must use and it isn't feasible to get an indicator to replace it, then this might be a workaround:
  Install xfce4-panel
 (see [Can I use GNOME applets in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10597/can-i-use-gnome-applets-in-unity))

Then I added xcfe4-panel and gbirthday to the startup applications. 
After restart: I chose to get an empty panel, added the notification area to the panel and set it to Auto-hide. Afterwards arranged the panel in such a way as to not bother other parts of your system, i.e in the lower-right corner.
This worked for me although I hope the workaround from Omegamormegil will for me as well.