# Do you know any birthday reminder alternative to GBirthday?

Tags: unity, software-recommendation, evolution

I use the very useful and small birthday (and more) reminder tool [**Gbirthday**](http://gbirthday.sourceforge.net) a lot, but there is no Unity indicator for it (at least not yet, unless someone **creates** it) and [you have to whitelist the notification applet for the panel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72144/gbirthday-is-there-a-way-to-let-it-work-with-unity).

Is there a good alternative **birthday reminder** that works with **Unity**?
And that gets the dates from the Evolution addressbook/calendar?
Or a tool that gets the dates from a file that can be easily created with Evolution, so it can be done regularly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After waiting and searching for an answer/alternative for the birthday reminder status icon/indicator/tool [Gbirthday](http://gbirthday.sourceforge.net/) for 7 years, **I have not found any.** But fortunately Gbirthday is still alive. **It was ported to Qt and is called now [Qbirthday](https://github.com/lafrech/qbirthday).**
You can **install it in Ubuntu**, [instructions here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034936/how-to-install-qbirthday/1034937#1034937).

Answer (score 1):

You could try google calendar and then add 'Google' under 'Online Accounts' in 'System Settings'. This will pop reminders up for appointments you have made on your Google calendar in unity.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, but I prefer a solution I don't need internet connection to update the information.

Comment: Also, 'Online Accounts' isn't displayed in system settings in a standard 12.04 install - at least in my experience. See this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-online-accounts/+bug/950352)