# How to install qbirthday?

Tags: software-installation, indicator

[Qbirthday](https://github.com/lafrech/qbirthday) is great app (a Qt port of GBirthday, a GTK application), mainly a **birthday reminder** status icon or indicator in the top panel.
It features several backends available (CSV file, Lightning, MySQL databse), is extendable to other backends and has iCalendar export.
How can it be installed in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download the zip-folder from the [github-page](https://github.com/lafrech/qbirthday) by clicking on the green button (`Code`) and choose download as zip-folder.
Navigate to the folder which contains the zip-folder, extract it.
In the terminal direct the command line into the extracted folder location (which ends with /qbirthday-master) with

```
cd >extracted folder's location<

sudo pip install qbirthday
```

*In older Ubuntu versions, python 2.7 is the default for pip, you have to install pip3:*

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

*And then install Qbirthday (being still in the folder's location):*

```
pip3 install qbirthday
```

*I had to restart the computer to be able to use Qbirthday from the command line.*

If you want to see the **indicator in the panel**, you may have to install or activate the GNOME extension [gnome-shell-extension-appindicator](https://github.com/ubuntu/gnome-shell-extension-appindicator) (Turn off [Ubuntu AppIndicators](https://extensions.gnome.org//extension/1301/ubuntu-appindicators/), it doubled the indicator icons and the double click did not work):

- One click on the indicator icon: Reveal indicator menus upon.
- Double clicking an icon will activate the application window.

You have to probably create a **desktop-file** ([see other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/64237/30631)) with the content to be able to use it from a **launcher**:
[Desktop Entry]

```
Name=QBirthday
Exec=qbirthday
Type=Application
Categories=Office;
Icon=qbirthday
_Comment=Birthday reminder
Name[en_GB]=QBirthday
```

And place it in the folder `.local/share/applications`, make it executable.
Adding it to the Startup Applications is also handy, just qbirthday as new entry.

**PS: Two issues were found, maybe somebody can help to solve them:**

1. [Pop-up window from panel indicator/icon too much to the left, not fully visible](https://github.com/lafrech/qbirthday/issues/13), see also [launchpad bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1777240).
   **Workaround**: Reduce the numbers of displayed birthdays in the preferences until the window is not anymore too tall for the screen and the window is fully visible.
2. [Double click needed to open birthday list](https://github.com/lafrech/qbirthday/issues/14)
   Maybe the Qbirthday app can be forked to be **a [GNOME extension](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Extensions/StepByStepTutorial)**, there is no birthday GNOME extension yet.