# How to have gnome-applet's functionality with unity?

Tags: unity, applet

with gnome-fallback and classic gnome shell, we had `gnome applets` available, but not in Unity. There was a system monitoring applet there that I could see may CPU and network bandwith used. I'm pretty sure that I can not have the same applets in Unity, at least not yet, from [Can I use GNOME applets in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10597/can-i-use-gnome-applets-in-unity). But how can I have such functionality with unity that shows me my system status in the upper panel? Or how can I create such thing?

Edit: One possible way might be to create a program to monitor network and changing icon in notification area is one way in order to show status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case I found another package that ported gnome classic applet (with some changes) for Unity. It is named `indicator-multiload` and it available from default Ubuntu repositories. I installed it by

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-multiload
```

More informations can be seen here http://www.webupd8.org/2011/06/indicator-multiload-update-brings.html

Answer (score 0):

answering to your generic question about gnome applets, you can look at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39069/how-do-i-use-the-gnome-panel-in-unity)

basically you run `gnome-panel`, remove what you dont want from it with **alt+super+rightClick** and add what you want too; now I can finally access the "cpu frequency scaling monitor" after more than a year...